# How to create lines for all cells of the table (pgfplotstable)

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

How to create lines for all cells of the table in a package **pgfplotstable**?

There is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset [] {
a b
5000 1.234e5
6000 1.631e5
7000 2.1013e5
9000 1000000
}
\end{document}
```

I want to get something like it:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `booktabs` way of avoiding vertical lines are adopted in `pgfplotstable`. Hence the options are a little more laborous than the `toprule, midrule, bottomrule` usage.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{ucs}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
before row=\hline,every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
columns/a/.style={column type=|c},
columns/b/.style={column type=|c|},
]{
a b
5000 1.234e5
6000 1.631e5
7000 2.1013e5
9000 1000000
}
\end{document}
```

This gives you the result in your image. The alternative is to go about the `booktabs` style.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{ucs}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs} 
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{
a b
5000 1.234e5
6000 1.631e5
7000 2.1013e5
9000 1000000
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm really not that opinionated as the argument goes in the manual of `booktabs` but indeed the second one has more appeal for my taste.

Comment: Thank you very much! It turned out, that it is quite easy.

Comment: Special thanks for the suggestion of second variant. Unfortunately, I should use the predetermined style in my work now, but I will remember your advice)

Comment: @QueueOverflow My pleasure.